# Algorithm faster than BMH (Boyer–Moore–Horspool) Search

Tags: algorithm, search, string, full-text-search

Which algorithm would you use to search short substrings in short texts? By short I mean 5-10 characters for substring and 255 for the string. I'm thinking about choosing algorithm depending on input data length. Which algorithm is better for longer inputs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [Turbo-BM](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node15.html). However, IMO, with such short strings usual linear scan will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for a algorithm better than Boyer Moore, then you are asking for a mixed answer.

That I know of, only the suffix tree beats the Boyer Moore in text search. However it uses more time to create the index and uses more disk space.

Additional info:
Speed wise the Suffix tree or the Suffix array beats any version of the Boyer Moore because the suffix tree basically implements all possible searches in a tree like data structure.

However the Suffix trees have a high ram memory cost and are slower to index text (create the tree data structure).

Speed difference on a Boyer Moore vs the Suffix tree:
Boyer Moore is linear on the search Text.
Suffix Tree is linear on the search Pattern.

If you are searching for 5 letter words on a 200 character text the boyer moore does 200 operations and the suffix tree does 5.

However faster it maybe, it is very hard to implement. On the difficulty scale of data structures it is probably one of the hardest. And once built it can be vastly optimized for space and speed.

This said, look for suffix tree in the coming years.
Typically the suffix trees are used for DNA indexing and web search engines optimization.

Boyer Moore is used everywhere, for example convention programs (text search function) and widely in web search engines.

Comment: You are comparing *Suffix tree* to the full *Boyer Moore text search*, while the question poses *Boyer-Moore-Horspool* (which drops "The Good Suffix Rule") as a reference. `look for suffix tree in the coming years` ignored [suffix arrays](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array), notoriously hard to implement (even in comparison to suffix trees) with manageable construction procedures published in the noughties ([and a half decent one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.00865) in 2017).

Answer (score 1):

@anon @Anton Gogolev
To answer your question in one word:
Railgun_Quadruplet

This C function is so heavily tested on short 2,3,4 patterns vs 160 characters strings that looking on this table http://www.sanmayce.com/Railgun/index.html#Heavy-Search-Hustle you can decide by yourself.

An article also at:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Railgun_Quadruplet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Suffix Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) or [Suffix Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array). Both depend on the pattern length.

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach and *may* beat BMH.  This is similar to BMH but continues aligning the succeeding text characters after the last text character and until the current text character can't be aligned or until no more pattern characters to align.  The preprocessing builds a table of the next position of any character at every pattern position. For example:

```
Pattern:  ABCABC
          012345
```

The next C at position 5 is 5 itself, while the next C at position 4 is 2.  The next position of characters not found in the pattern is -1.  The following is the Java code:

```
public class BoyerMooreHorspool {

    int[] tab1 = new int[256];
    int[][] tab2 = new int[1000][1000];
    int[] tab3 = new int[1000];

    public BoyerMooreHorspool() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tab1.length; i++) {
            tab1[i] = 999;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            tab2[999][i] = -1;
        }
    }

    public void processPattern(char[] pattern) {
        int i, j, p;

        for (i = 0; i < pattern.length; ++i) {
            tab1[pattern[i]] = -1;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < pattern.length; ++i) {
            tab3[i] = tab1[pattern[i]];
            tab1[pattern[i]] = i;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
            p = tab1[pattern[i]];

            for (j = tab3[i] + 1; j < i; j++) {
                tab2[p][j] = tab3[i];
            }
            if (i == p) {
                for (j = i; j < pattern.length; j++) {
                    tab2[p][j] = i;
                }
            } else {
                tab2[p][i] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    public int search(char[] text, char[] pattern) {
        int k = pattern.length - 1;
        int i, j, oi, ok;
        int lpos = k;

        while (k < text.length) {
            j = k;
            ok = k;
            i = tab2[tab1[text[j]]][lpos];
            k += lpos - i;
            j--;
            i--;
            while (i > -1) {
                oi = i;
                i = tab2[tab1[text[j]]][i];
                k += oi - i;
                j--;
                i--;
            }
            if (ok == k) {
                return j + 1;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public int search(String origText, String origPattern) {
        char[] text = origText.toCharArray();
        char[] pattern = origPattern.toCharArray();

        processPattern(pattern);
        int res = search(text, pattern);

        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
            tab1[pattern[i]] = 999;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```